# What are the other synonyms of Persona?

Tags: nouns, synonyms

I learned the word from my UX team. They do this exercise where they put users into different buckets based on their characteristics and behavior. These buckets are called Personas.

What are the other words with the same meaning?

Yes, I googled the word and couldn't find anything convincing.
According to thesaurus.com, synonyms of Persona are personality, card, crank, figure, oddity, case, clown etc.

Are their other nouns which have similar meaning as Persona?

Comment: In terms of software dev, you could use 'role', 'portfolio', etc. A persona in this context is essentially what type of user someone is. I.e., the site may behave differently if you're a member versus a guest, so there is a guest persona and a member persona that the devs will consider when building in functionality.

Comment: User Types, User Profiles, Kinds of User...

Comment: *character*, *part*, *role*

Comment: _identity_, _user id_, _alias_, _profile_, _user account_

Comment: @trpt4him - I don’t think those equate with *persona*.  A persona is used as a class of user in user stories and use case analysis.

Comment: Character type.